# Different results with thread in Python 2/3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Below is the code in Python 3. It always can get 100000. Why it is wrong? I think it should have different results.

```
import time, _thread

global count
count = 0
def test():
    global count

    for i in range(0, 10000):
        count += 1

for i in range(0, 10):
    _thread.start_new_thread(test, ())
time.sleep(5)
print(count)
```

Below is the code in Python 2. It always has different result (random).

```
import time, thread

global count
count = 0
def test():
    global count

    for i in range(0, 10000):
        count += 1

for i in range(0, 10):
    thread.start_new_thread(test, ())
time.sleep(5)
print count
```

Comment: Python 3 is far faster at iterating through loops, try set `sleep(1)` and `i in range(10000)`

Comment: See my answer:  it's not really that iteration is faster in Python 3.  It's that the criteria for _when_ to allow threads to switch changed.

Answer (score 5):

CPython 2 allowed threads to switch after a certain number of byte codes had executed; CPython 3.2 changed to allow threads to switch after a certain amount of time has passed.  Your `test()` executes plenty of byte codes, but consumes little time.  On my box, under Python 3 the displayed result becomes unpredictable if I add, e.g., this near the start:

```
import sys
sys.setswitchinterval(sys.getswitchinterval() / 10.0)
```

That is, allow threads to switch after 10 times less time (than the default) has elapsed.

Also note that `_thread` is strongly discouraged in Python 3:  that's why the leading underscore was added.  Using `threading.Thread` instead, like:

```
for i in range(10):
    t = threading.Thread(target=test)
    t.start()
```